# ionic build android not producing any .apk file or error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on publishing my second application and am having problems publishing android.

When running `cordova build --release android` it's supposed to produce an apk file in `platforms/android/build/outputs/apk` according to the [docs](http://community.reallifeglobal.com) and previous experience. For some reason, nothing is happening. It doesn't give me any error message, and doesn't create the .apk file (there is no build folder).

I believe something is messed up with my environment, but can't figure out what or where to start. `ionic run android` does not work either, similar thing where no error message is output, just does nothing. The device is ready according to `adb devices`. `cordova run android` also has a similar problem, where nothing happens but no error.

I did find that `ionic build --release android --verbose` gives me a little bit of info

```
Looking up Ionic root, cwd: /Users/awwester/Mobile/ionic/joeapp
Ionic root directory:  /Users/awwester/Mobile/ionic/joeapp
Gulpfile found
ConfigXml.setConfigXml /Users/awwester/Mobile/ionic/joeapp resetContent=true, errorWhenNotFound=false
Cordova is installed: true
Executing cordova cli: build --release android --verbose
```

I don't think this gives us any useful info, but it's the most info I've found on why nothing is happening. Please let me know any more info I can supply to help solve this issue.

```
Ionic Info
Cordova CLI: 5.1.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
Ionic Framework Version: 1.2.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.25
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.15
ios-deploy version: 1.8.5
ios-sim version: 5.0.7
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v5.10.1
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3 Build version 7D175
```

Comment: can you try to remove android platform and readding again

Comment: hey thanks. I did that `ionic platform remove android` `ionic platform add android` but same results

Comment: i didn't meet this one before , what is your ionic info ?

Comment: @AbdouTelb just added the ionic info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a version problem with cordova. I needed to update cordova from 5.1.1 to 6.2.0 and that solved the issue.

More info on github https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/593